# LiveData_LifecycleBoundObserver_LifecycleAdapter cannot be cast to GeneratedAdapter

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am using `kotlin` in my android studio project and I'm trying to add an observer to a `MutableLiveData` which contains an `ArrayList` but I'm getting the exception below.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData_LifecycleBoundObserver_LifecycleAdapter cannot be cast to android.arch.lifecycle.GeneratedAdapt
    at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.createGeneratedAdapter(Lifecycling.java:79)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.getCallback(Lifecycling.java:62)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.<init>(LifecycleRegistry.java:346)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:162)
    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:199)
```

**project level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha05'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**app's build.gradle**

```
android {      
    dataBinding {
        enabled true;
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
//...
}
```

**my activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //...
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Media>>()
    //...
    liveData.observe(this, object : Observer<ArrayList<Media>>{
            override fun onChanged(t: ArrayList<Media>?) {
                if(t?.size!! > 0){
                    binding.totalTv.text =t.size.toString()
                    binding.totalTv.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
    })
    //...
}
```

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions`

From

```
 implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
```

To

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
```

then synced my project and it was successful. Thanks to @MatPag for insight

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your piece of code with:

- `dataBinding {
      enabled true
  }`
- `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to  Java 8
- `gradle 4.2.1`
- `android plugin 3.0.1`
- `kotlin plugin 1.2.10`

Dependencies:

- `appcompat-v7 27.0.2`
- `android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3`
- `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0`
- `android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0`

And everything is working fine...